# fetch json data

Tags: ios, json, nsurlrequest

i am now developing a iOS app

I have a web service that contains some user data.

Once I use URLRequest to get the data, it is smooth and I really get the amount of data I wanted from the server.

```
theRequest = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]
                         initWithURL: [NSURL URLWithString:URL]
                         cachePolicy: NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData
                         timeoutInterval: 10
                         ];
```

//////////////////

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
// do something with the data
// receivedData is declared as a method instance elsewhere
NSLog(@"Succeeded! Received %d bytes of data", [receivedData length]);

switch (getType) {
    case 0:
    default:
        [delegate performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(didFinishDownloadLoad:) withObject:receivedData waitUntilDone:false];
```

But the question is , I need to fetch the data to the uitableviecell.

If I contains 10 lists of data, I need to loop 10 times to init the data.

It will " freeze" my app, I cannot do anything when I am fetching the data

What should I do in order to "not Freeze" my app?

#### ////update**

```
-(void) didFinishDownloadLoad:(NSMutableData*)receivedData{

NSData *theData = [[NSData alloc] initWithData:receivedData];
NSError *theError = nil;

NSMutableArray *tmparray = [NSMutableArray array];

NSDictionary *theObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:theData options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&theError];
NSLog(@"theObject:%@",theObject);
    
    
NSDictionary *theList = [theObject objectForKey:@"list"];
    
    for (NSString *s in theList)
    {

        NSDictionary *theNewFeed = [theList objectForKey:s];
        NewFeedDetailsManager *newFeedDetails = [[NewFeedDetailsManager alloc] init];
        [newFeedDetails setCid:s];
        [newFeedDetails setFbid:[theNewFeed objectForKey:@"fbid"]];
        [newFeedDetails setFbUserName:[theNewFeed objectForKey:@"fbname"]];
        [newFeedDetails setUserComment:[theNewFeed objectForKey:@"comment"]];
        [newFeedDetails setRestaurantName:[theNewFeed objectForKey:@"name"]];
        [newFeedDetails setRestaurantAddress:[theNewFeed objectForKey:@"address"]];
        [newFeedDetails setWriteDate:[theNewFeed objectForKey:@"date"]];
        [newFeedDetails setSid:[theNewFeed objectForKey:@"sid"]];
        
        //get User Pro Pic
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/%@/picture", newFeedDetails.fbid]];
        newFeedDetails.userimage = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url]];
        
        [tmparray addObject:newFeedDetails];
    }
}
```

Thank all and now I get the problem..

it is freezing in" getting user profile picture"
NSURL method needs to take time to get the picture... so it will freeze my app

so, What should I do in order to get the profile picture and not to freeze my app?

Comment: What code do you have on didFinishDownloadLoad? Since it is running on the main thread the reason for the freezing is probably there. Nevertheless, I would suggest for you to use a library like AFNetworking to do your requests.

Comment: I have update the problem. It is freezing due to the fucntion "NSURL" on didFinishDownloadLoad.

Anyway, thank you,
Is there any suggestions/pro to use AFNetwoking?

Comment: For instance, AFNetworking has convenient methods to asynchronously load images (since that was your freezing problem).

Comment: Thank you joao, I am now trying to use AFNetworking for instead!

Answer (score 1):

Your code is using asynchronous methods of NSURLConnection. So that part of the code will not cause your code to freeze. If your table view is not scrolling smoothly, it is likely due to the code that you have put in the main thread (maybe what the code does in didFinishDownloadLoad).

Comment: Yeah!!:) you are right, there is the function "NSURL" to get the profile pic that "freeze" my app, because I have to wait for the image be downloaded(This concept is wrong")

Thank You!

Comment: Glad that I could help. Would be great if you can accept the answer.